# Slidify: Alignment of Codes

Tags: r, slidify

I have problem with the alignment of the codes in two column slide.

[image]

Here is my code for this slide,

````
--- &twocol

## Sample R Codes

*** =left

```{r, echo=FALSE}
options(width=30)
```


```{r, fig.height=5.5,highlight=TRUE, fig.show='hide',tidy=TRUE}
mvreg.sim <- function(xcov,beta1=matrix(c(0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7), 
             nr = 2, nc = 2),  err.mu=c(0,0), 
             err.sigma=matrix(c(100,0,0,100), nr=2)){
  library(mvtnorm)
  N <- nrow(xcov)
  e <- rmvnorm(N, mean = err.mu, sigma = err.sigma)  
  y <- matrix(NA, nrow = N, ncol = 2)
  for(i in 1:N){
    y[i,] <- (xcov[i,])%*%beta1 + e[i,]
  }
  return(y)
}
```

*** =right

This is the explanation of the plot.

```{r, fig.height=5.5,highlight=TRUE,echo=FALSE}
x <- seq(0,10, by = 0.01)
y <- x
plot(x, sin(y), xlab = 'x-axis', ylab = 'sin(x)', main = 'Sample Plot')
```
````

I am new to slidify with little knowledge on html. I use `tidy=TRUE` with `options(width=60)` to control the width of the codes inside the box, but the alignment somehow is affected. I want the alignment set to right justified. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trouble is because the default two column layout in Slidify center aligns the left column (I will fix it in the next version). This is the two column template used.

```
---
layout: slide
---
{{{ slide.content }}}
<div style='float:left;width:48%;' class='centered'>
  {{{ slide.left.html }}}
</div>
<div style='float:right;width:48%;'>
  {{{ slide.right.html }}}
</div>
```

Easiest fix would be to save the above layout as `twocol.html` in the directory `assets/layouts` and then remove `class = "centered"`. Custom layouts automatically override system layouts. Just make sure that you drop the file in `assets/layouts` since that is the location where Slidify will look for custom layouts.

Comment: Is there a mechanism to inherit layout?

Comment: Yes. A very simple mechanism though. For example, the twocol layout inherits from the slide layout, and merely replaces {{{ slide.content }}} with content from the child. It is easy to extend this mechanism to do arbitrary replacements, but I haven't found a good use case yet to support this.